# Structuring Zend_Acl and CRUD with Parent/Child Relationships

Tags: zend-framework, acl, zend-acl

I am wondering how should I structure my ACL for CRUD with Parent/Child Relations.

Eg. Projects have TodoLists. TodoLists have Todos

There are various controller actions for project

- /projects/add
- /projects/edit/{projId}
- /projects/delete/{projId}
- /todo-lists/add/{projId}
- /todo-lists/edit/{todoListId}
- ...

As you can see going down the hierarchy, some actions have ids that refer not to themselves (eg. todo-lists controller -> todo-list resource) but to their parent

So with with I have setup (generally), it looks like this

- ACL Controller Plugin (preDispatch)

  - Set role to loggedin user or 'unauthenticated'
  - Set resource to controller name
  - Set privilege to action name
  - if request param 'id' is set, get the actual entity (I am using Doctrine ORM) that implements `Zend_Acl_Resource_Interface`. Here is where the complication arises. I will usually get the resource from the controller name, but for eg. with `/todo-lists/add` I must know to get the parent entity instead (Project). With this setup, I will have to chage the privilege to to something like 'addTodoList'. This way, the project acl assertion class will have to TodoLists stuff. There will also be a disconnect between Controller Actions & ACL Logic. Is that ok?

Maybe I should have addTodoListAction in ProjectsController instead of TodoListsController? This will simplify my ACL code, I won't need to check and modify resource/privileges? I can just take these directly from the request params (Controller & Action names).

How do you setup ACL's like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use Zend_Acl_Assertion , create your assertion for projectid and todoId. At the time of giving permission do

```
$myAcl->allow($role,'projects','edits',new My_Project_Assertion());
```

and you cannot use action "addTodoListAction" because of captial letters (or define your own dispatcher) addtodolistAction wd work;